# MySQL - Transaction deadlock - Waiting for the metadata lock even after Server Restart

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb

We have a MySQL (8.0.X-google) version in GCP which holds few databases. Recently we are stuck due to the "***Waiting for table metadata lock***" error for the alter query on one of the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD COLUMN `my_column` VARCHAR(64) NULL AFTER `last_column`
```

I tried following steps to find out the deadlock but could not get the lock cleared.

1. Tried to check the operations which could be blocking by running - `show full processlist`
2. Killed all the threads including which are sleeping
3. Ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` and looked for the threads which might have locked - No thread ids found. I can see 1 table locked when the above query is waiting for metadata lock.
4. Restarted DB Server

But still not able to add new column to that table. Any clues?

Comment: This sounds like a [lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lock_wait_timeout), not a deadlock. Are you able to check `performance_schema.metadata_locks` to see which lock is pending, and what currently holds the lock?

Comment: @user1191247 I can see two records in Pending state. One exclusive and other SHARED_UPGRADABLE on same table I am trying to alter. Also can see that the lock_wait_timeout is set to high value - i.e. 1 year.

Comment: But when I killed the processes waiting for metadata lock; I dont see any pending lock in metadata_locks. I can see few other locks in Granted state.

Comment: Does it say which table(s) are involved?  Do you know what query started it?  Which exact version of 8.0 is it?

Comment: You could try using a query like [this](https://pastebin.com/avZ8KVu2) to see what is blocking - [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/avZ8KVu2). How many rows in this table and what is the average row size? Are there FK constraints to/from this table? Please add details to your question, not as comments.